# Deadlock while writing to Process.StandardInput

Tags: c#, deadlock

I'm developping an application and I have a problem with a deadlock.

My code looks like that :

```
Process p = new Process(); // That using an other application
```

Then I'm sending an .xml-file to this process:

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var sw = new StreamWriter(ms);
    XmlWriter xmlwriter = XmlWriter.Create(sw, xmlWriterSettings);
    xmlwriter.WriteProcessingInstruction("PipeConfiguratorStyleSheet", processing);
    xs.Serialize(xmlwriter, data);
    xmlwriter.Flush();
    ms.Position = 0;
    var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        String line = sr.ReadLine();
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(line);                
        Console.WriteLine(line);
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.CancelOutputRead(); 
    }
}
```

So actually I can send a part of my .xml-file to my process but at some point I'll get a deadlock.
I guess I don't knoy how to use `BeginOutputReadLine()` correctly.

Comment: isn't there a method to use the Process-instance directly as a stream? like `xs.Serialize(p.StandardInput, data)`?

Comment: Are you sure the receiving side is reading the data in? If the receiving side is not reading when the buffer gets full you can get blocked. Do you have the code for the receiving side?

Comment: how do you encounter the deadlock? I am asking, because there is no `lock` - so it is not fully obvious, to me, how there should be a hang (which could be described as a deadlock)...

Comment: I don't know really. I used a basic Write() / Read() but it's a synchronized method. And according to my research i have to use desynchronized method as BeginOutputReadLine().

Comment: Why are you calling canceloutputread()? Can you locate where it's deadlocking at? Deadlock occurs when there is a contention for the same resource, so I'm not seeing where it can occur.

Comment: In this code, i'm printing the data that i send to my process, it's the "line" variable that correspond each lines of my .xml-file. So in the console, my program start to print maybe 100-200 lines of my xml and he still locked at 1 "standard" data line. I think it's because my process send me an answer and i don't read this properly.

Comment: In my opinion, it's a pipe to send data to my process so, i send data but i never read what is my process"s answers. So i probably need to flush my StandardOutput(). But how :s

Comment: Did you read the msdn-entry: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx? Did you implement the prerequisites, which are mentioned there?

Comment: Yes, "p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false" and "p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true" are implemented, but i don't know how to implement properly the third step. MSDN "Add your event handler to the OutputDataReceived event. The event handler must match the System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventHandler delegate signature."

Comment: @SteevenBrunner like so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx??

Comment: It's the same code than the last documentation. Already, I don't know if i've to use BeginOutputReadLine() in my loop or out of my loop. In all example that i found, there was no loop that wrote any thing to a process.

Comment: @SteevenBrunner please incorporate @-tags to your comments - otherwise people won't get notified... aaaand: I've already added an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, why don't you use the `Process.StandardInput`-property directly as your target, like

```
var process = new Process
{
    // all your init stuff
};
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
var xmlwriter = XmlWriter.Create(process.StandardInput, xmlWriterSettings);
xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlwriter, data);
```

Otherwise, the [msdn-entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx) gives a clear howto for using `Process.BeginOutputReadLine()`, which you can remodel to

```
var autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false); // this mutex acts as our bouncer for the reading-part
var process = new Process
{
    // all your init stuff
};
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => {
    // TODO you could read the content here with args.Data
    autoResetEvent.Set();
};
process.Start();

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
        var xmlwriter = XmlWriter.Create(streamWriter, xmlWriterSettings);
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(xmlwriter, data);
    }
    memoryStream.Position = 0;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
    {
        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine(line);

            Console.WriteLine(line);

            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}

// TODO closing the process.StandardInput, exiting process, ...
```

Anyway - I know this should be a comment - is there a specific reason why you are waiting for your process to write something?

> The StandardOutput stream can be read synchronously or asynchronously.
>   Methods such as Read, ReadLine, and ReadToEnd perform synchronous read
>   operations on the output stream of the process. These synchronous read
>   operations do not complete until the associated Process writes to its
>   StandardOutput stream, or closes the stream. In contrast,
>   BeginOutputReadLine starts asynchronous read operations on the
>   StandardOutput stream. This method enables a designated event handler
>   for the stream output and immediately returns to the caller, which can
>   perform other work while the stream output is directed to the event
>   handler.

Which means, that if your process does not write anything (and you are waiting), you are spinning for response endlessly ...

**EDIT**

You should additionally add a handler to [`Process.ErrorDataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.errordatareceived.aspx) like

```
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => {
    // TODO do something with the response of args.Data
    autoResetEvent.Set();
};
```

and

```
while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(line);

    Console.WriteLine(line);

    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

to handle error-cases as well (whatever that may mean).

Comment: The program isn't work like that for me. I'll try to resolve errors with your answers and send the final code. Thk a lot.

Comment: Hi, after some data print i got this error :An async read operation has already been started on the stream. Do you know how can i resolve this ? Thank's.

Comment: @SteevenBrunner This happens when you call `.BeginOutputReadLine()` without previously being called-back with `.OutputDataReceived`. This is why I've used `AutoResetEvent`. Which approach did you actually tried and which are you currently using? Could you propably put this information in your question?

Comment: My program works now. The problem was that i didn't read the error output, my process returned somes warning so that blocked the execution. I didn't used the autoResetEvent() because my process didn't returned each times something. Thank's a lot for your help =)

Comment: @SteevenBrunner I've adapted my answer and added a hint for adding an error-handler as well.